# Angular. How to fill formArray with data with restoring field structure?

Tags: angular, forms, formarray, dynamicform

I have a Angular dynamic form with several sections. The section can be `formGroup` and `formArray`. And each section can also have a `formGroup` and a `formArray`. I want to implement rollback of unsaved form changes. To do this, I have a set of values ​​from the last save, which I take from the `NGRX` store. And when the changes are rolled back, I fill the form with data using patchValue. However, if during the editing of the form the fields were removed from the `formArray`, then `patchValue` will fill with data only those fields that are available. How can you restore the configuration of a form with the correct number of `formArray`, without using manual iteration of all fields?

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. To improve this question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then edit your question. Show what you got, what you aim for, and what you get and make clear what your problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one of the solution:

Create a function that will initialize the formGroup with formArray, formGroup fields based on the values that you get from ngrx store from the last save.

All the changes will be done in the form group - sections can be added, removed, or edited.

Now, in case if changes need to be rolled back, then simply call that function again. This will reinitialize the form with the values from ngrx store of the last save and hence the edited changes will be removed.

If the changes are saved, then make the changes in the ngrx store